# Has-bouncing in ionic doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Ok firstly, I'm a newbie at Ionic so I may have misunderstood some of the documentation.

I have an ion-content that has the has-bouncing="true" like so.

```
<ion-view view-title="{{currentView.viewName}}">
  <ion-content has-bouncing="true">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="pdr in currentViewPDRs" href="#/app/pdr/{{pdr.pdrId}}">
        <h1>{{pdr.pdrId}}</h1>

        <i>{{pdr.desc}}</i>
        <p>{{pdr.status}}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I haven't done much else and I've just using the default sidemenu template here.

I assume that having has-bouncing=true means that when it gets to the end of the page, it'll have a bounce back effect. Instead, it just stops at the end of the page and does not give the user any feedback.

I've tried this on chrome, firefox and uploaded to my Android ionic view app and the behaviour is exactly the same.

Am I misunderstanding what has-bouncing is supposed to do? If so, how do I get some animation to provide feedback for when the user has reached the bottom of a page?

Comment: actually it working fine for me i don't know whats wrong in your app, but if you looking for a paging functionality in your app  you can use `ion-infinite-scroll` directive , you can check the link below for more information.
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/

Answer (score 3):

Had bounce working once and then it stopped. 
This is what original was written:

```
<ion-content class=" has-header" scroll="true" has-bouncing="true">
```

Changed into this and bouncing came back:

```
<ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="false" has-bouncing="true">
```